# What's the name of the rendering problem I describe here?

Tags: c++, rendering

I don't remember how is it called that rendering problem that you have when you get fast movements (a sprite moves fast for example from right to left) and you have half of the image in a position and half in another for a given frame (for example the top left of the sprite moves correctly but the bottom half of the same sprite is lagging back).

In particular I'm using SFML2 but this is kinda a Library-Agnostic question.

And what are the most common methods to fix it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are probably referring to [tearing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Screen_tearing). You should enable VSync and/or use multiple buffering.